# how can I get the length of an uint64_t value

Tags: c

how do I get the length of an int (uint64_t) e.g. 1 -> 1 100 -> 3, ...
using only the functions available in `stdint.h`.

One way I thought of is using a loop:

```
int len = 0; 
while (i != 0) {
i/=10; 
len ++; }
```

But Im sure that there are more efficient ways to do this.

Comment: There aren't really any functions defined or declared in the "stdint.h" header file.

Comment: ... but you could 'compact' your loop to, say: `for (len = 0; i != 0; ++len, i /= 10) {}`.

Comment: You can calculate the logarithm base 10, but it probably won't be faster than the loop.